# View is behaving fixed sized instead of dynamic sized based on screen using ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a setting screen, below is the code and preview in Android Studio.

It has a couple of issues. The CardView with the scrollView layout is not working as it should

What I want is, my `CardView` to be adjusted in the middle of `userDetailsLayout` and `logoutBtn` with the spacing of `@dimen/_20sdp`. But it can be seen that its stretching all the way to logoutBtn,

If I use a small screen mobile, the CardView, also starts overlapping `userDetailsLayout`

It's like, its making `CardView` fixed size instead of variable-sized based on space. What should I do?

```
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userDetailsLayout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/logoutBtn"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/forgot_bg_color"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                           android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                           android:src="@drawable/down_arrow"
                           android:scaleType="centerInside"
                           android:rotation="90"
                           android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                           android:layout_above="@+id/inboxBtn"
                           android:id="@+id/backBtn"
                />

                <TextView
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/backBtn"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/inboxBtn"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        android:text="@string/action_settings"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                        android:id="@+id/homeTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/inboxBtn"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/userDetailsLayout"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/topBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
    >


            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/userLayout"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
            >

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/userDp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userLayout"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            >


                <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
                        android:text="@string/action_settings"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

                <TextView
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                        android:text="@string/action_settings"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
                        android:id="@+id/details"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userDetailsLayout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/logoutBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

        <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                          android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            >

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                >

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:text="@string/notifications"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                    <Switch android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                />

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                >

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:text="@string/manage_address"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_small"
                               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                />

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                >

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:text="@string/about"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_small"
                               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                />

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                >

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:text="@string/support"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_small"
                               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                />

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                >

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:text="@string/terms"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_small"
                               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                />

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                >

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                            android:text="@string/privacy"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

                    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_small"
                               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                />

            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/logout"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/logout_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean, but from the code I would suggest you to change:

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
```

when you specify height and width constraints on the view. Otherwise the constraints won't work. And btw. dont use so many nested layouts inside your constraintlayout. Every single layout will need a complete new measure and render process which slow down your app a lot. Please also look at `Guidelines` and `ConstraintAspectRatio`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `logoutBtn` is within the same parent as your `CardView`. They both have

```
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
```

That's why they have the same width, they both align right and left to the parent and have the same about of margin. So if you want it to be **20dp** from the `CardView` you either want to nest the `logoutBtn` in the cardview or simply make the `logoutBtn` have **40dp**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@color/error_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="string/logout"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    />
```